# How to change path to Node-RED Dashboard

Tags: iot, node-red

By default the Node-RED Dashboard UI lives on the http://example.com:1880/ui route and the Node-RED editor lives on http://example.com/.

I would like to move the Dashboard UI to http://example.com/ and the editor to another path.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You want to access a Pi remotely without using the user interface?  Like with ssh?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by editing the `settings.js` file in the Node-RED user directory (normally ~/.node-red)

uncomment the `httpAdmnRoot` key

```
// By default, the Node-RED UI is available at http://localhost:1880/
// The following property can be used to specifiy a different root path.
// If set to false, this is disabled.
httpAdminRoot: '/admin',
```

and also uncomment and edit the `ui` entry:

```
// If you installed the optional node-red-dashboard you can set it's path
// relative to httpRoot
ui: { path: "/" },
```

After restarting Node-RED the editor will be on http://example.com:1880/admin and the Dashboard UI will be on http://example.com:1880/

Comment: this totally worked for me and should be the accepted answer